# Оптимизация повторяющегося кода CSS

Tags: css, html5, вёрстка, svg, css-animation

Я взял этот код из другого вопроса здесь. Он работает, однако, мне кажется, что  CSS используется не эффективно. Как я могу еще больше сократить / уменьшить CSS-код?

Такое ощущение, что слишком много повторов в `@keyframes`. Кроме того, я не уверен, почему используется цикл, но когда я удаляю его, все перестает работать.

PS: В демоверсии вы видите пример только для значений десять, тридцать и девяносто. На самом деле, я добавлю еще значения: двадцать, сорок, пятьдесят и т.д.

HTML:

```
    <div id="speedometer">
      <span class="barometer"></span>
      <span class="needle ten"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="speedometer">
      <span class="barometer"></span>
      <span class="needle thirty"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="speedometer">
      <span class="barometer"></span>
      <span class="needle ninety"></span>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    #speedometer {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
    }

    #speedometer .barometer {
      background-image: url("https://www.turbotobias.dk/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/barometer.svg");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 200px;
      height: 110px;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    #speedometer .needle {
      background-image: url("https://www.turbotobias.dk/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/needle.svg");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      z-index: 999999;
      width: 200px;
      height: 110px;
      display: inline-block;
      left: 0px;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 5px;
      transform-origin:50% calc(100% - 8px) ;
    }
    #speedometer .needle.ten {
      animation: changeTen 3s linear, loopTen 1s linear 3s infinite alternate;
    }
    @keyframes changeTen {
      0% { transform:rotate(-90deg); }
      100% { transform:rotate(-60deg); }
    }
    @keyframes loopTen {
      0% { transform:rotate(-60deg); }
      100% { transform:rotate(-60deg); }
    }
    #speedometer .needle.thirty {
      animation: changeThirty 3s linear, loopThirty 1s linear 3s infinite alternate;
    }
    @keyframes changeThirty {
      0% { transform:rotate(-90deg); }
      100% { transform:rotate(-30deg); }
    }
    @keyframes loopThirty {
      0% { transform:rotate(-30deg); }
      100% { transform:rotate(-30deg); }
    }
    #speedometer .needle.ninety {
      animation: changeNinety 3s linear, loopNinety 1s linear 3s infinite alternate;
    }
    @keyframes changeNinety {
      0% { transform:rotate(-90deg); }
      100% { transform:rotate(80deg); }
    }
    @keyframes loopNinety {
      0% { transform:rotate(80deg); }
      100% { transform:rotate(80deg); }
    }
`` `
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/58889460/7394871

Answer (score 3):

Используйте переменные CSS для устранения повторяющегося кода. Вы также можете уменьшить разметку только до одного элемента:

```css
.speedometer {
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url("https://www.turbotobias.dk/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/barometer.svg");
  width: 200px;
  overflow:hidden;
}


.speedometer:before {
  content:"";
  background-image: url("https://www.turbotobias.dk/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/needle.svg");
  height: 110px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  transform-origin:50% calc(100% - 8px) ;
  animation: change 3s linear forwards;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

@keyframes change {
  0% { transform:rotate(-90deg); }
  100% { transform:rotate(var(--r,90deg)); }
}
```

```html
<div class="speedometer" style="--r:-60deg;">
</div>
<div class="speedometer" style="--r:-30deg;">
</div>
<div class="speedometer" style="--r:80deg;">
</div>
```

Вы также можете сделать переменную более полезной, используя некоторые вычисления. Ниже я рассматриваю значения в диапазоне `[0 100]`

```css
.speedometer {
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url("https://www.turbotobias.dk/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/barometer.svg");
  width: 200px;
  overflow:hidden;
}


.speedometer:before {
  content:"";
  background-image: url("https://www.turbotobias.dk/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/needle.svg");
  height: 110px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  transform-origin:50% calc(100% - 8px) ;
  animation: change 3s linear forwards;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

@keyframes change {
  0% { transform:rotate(-90deg); }
  100% { transform:rotate(calc(1.8deg*var(--p) - 90deg)); }
}
```

```html
<div class="speedometer" style="--p:40;">
</div>
<div class="speedometer" style="--p:20;">
</div>
<div class="speedometer" style="--p:80;">
</div>
```

[Поддержка CSS переменных](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables)  -
   не поддерживает CSS Variables - **IE11**

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58889496/7394871): @Temani Afif

Comment: я прочитал статью https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties и у меня css-переменные заработали только когда я прописал псевдоэлемент :root так и должно работать ?

Comment: @Leks лучше конечно объявлять CSS переменные в :root, можно и как сделал автор ответа Enso `@Temani Afif`. Я проверил ещё раз, работает в Chrome, Firefox здесь в сниппете и если сохранить код в отдельном файле Опишите подробно, где у вас не работало Можете дать свой дополнительный ответ-решение прямо здесь

Comment: @ Alexandr_TT хорошо в течении  дня опишусь :)

Answer (score 1):

```css
:root {
  --main-color: hotpink;
  --pane-padding: 5px 42px;
}

.text{
  font-size: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  color: var(--main-color);
}
```

```html
<div class="text">text</div>
```

Comment: @Alexandr_TT что не правильно сделал ?

Comment: @ Leks Опечатка -- были лишние точки с запятой после закрывающих фигурных скобок

Comment: @Alexandr_TT  спасибо